# I get identical RE and OLS, although that should not be possible

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, least-squares, panel-data

I am attempting to model log price returns using a company specific variable and several macroeconomic variables on panel dataset. I have several hundred entity observations and 7 years of annual data. My OLS and random effects (RE) models return completely identical results, which is unrealistic, as there must be at least some variation across the entities but I cannot understand what exactly is wrong. I cannot share the company specific variable data but I also highly doubt that the issue lies within it. When I attempted to run models on another variable than log returns, the models were different. I have checked multiple times if the variable was transformed correctly and it 100% is. What could possibly be the reason?

The code below is just to show that I am not accidently running the same model.

```
ols1 <- plm( price_return ~ ESG + crisis + interest + subcos + evrps, data=df, model="pooling", effect = "individual") 

re1 <- plm( price_return ~ ESG + crisis + interest + subcos + evrps, data=df, model = "random", effect = "individual")
```

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Can you at least share a anonymized or simulated data based on your original variables?